# Navigate to View Controller from .xib file swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an issue. I have `.xib` file that am using to render some buttons. I want it such that when each of these buttons is clicked, it navigates to a new `viewController.` My logic doesnt work for me and i cant figure out what to do since this `.xib` layout is not embedded in a `UIViewController`.

**explore.xib**

```
 import UIKit

    protocol ExploreDelegate:UIViewController {
        func categoryClicked(category: ProductCategory)
    }

    //enum Categories: String, CaseIterable {
    //
    //}


    class Explore: UIView {

        @IBOutlet weak var electronics: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var mobilePhones: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var travel: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var womenFashion: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var menFashion: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var health: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var arts: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var babies: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var rentals: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var realEstate: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var agriculture: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var jobs: CategoryItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var everything: CategoryItem!


        var categoriesView: UIView!
        var titleLabel: UILabel!
        var delegate: ExploreDelegate?

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.setup()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            self.setup()
        }

        func configure() {
            let categoryButtons = [electronics, mobilePhones, travel, womenFashion, menFashion, health, arts, babies, rentals, realEstate, agriculture, jobs, everything]
            let categories: [ProductCategory] = ProductCategory.allCases
            categoryButtons.enumerated().forEach({
                $0.element?.category = categories[$0.offset]
            })        
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    class CategoryItem: UIView {

        var category: ProductCategory? {
            didSet {
                self.configure()
            }
        }
        var tapped: ((_ category: ProductCategory?) -> Void)?

        func configure() {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.categoryTapped)))
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        @objc func categoryTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
//here i want to navigate to new view controller but not working
            let newViewController = ProductLocationViewController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
            self.tapped?(self.category)
        }
    }
```

**Error**

```
value of type 'CategoryItem' has no member 'navigationController'
```

Please helpful ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your class inherit from UIView not from UIViewController ...

Comment: `UIViewController` have navigationController not `UIView`

Comment: can i make the class inherited both because UIView has to be there.

Comment: No, you cant inherit from both ... because swift has single inheritance

Comment: you can inject navigationController in view and use that ...

Comment: write a custom init() method in view to get Navigation

Comment: or ... this view is visible in a UIViewController .. you can ask that controller to navigate through delegation

Comment: please review line 2 of my code. I already have a protocol which i delegated a UIViewController to. Is that what you mean? I was expecting that to work,

Comment: when button categoryTapped pressed ... you should ask your parent controller to show `ProductLocationViewController` through protocol

Comment: do you have a code snippet for this?

Comment: For that i need to see your project ...

Comment: pelease review from this my other stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554053/delegating-action-through-protocol-not-working-swift