# Delegating action through protocol not working swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I needed to delegate a click action for my `UIView` class to my `UIViewController` class since Swift does not support multiple class inheritance. So i wanted it such that once a button is clicked on my subview, a function in my `BrowserViewController` class is called.

I am using a `protocol` to achieve this, but on the function does not triggered when the button is tapped. Please help me out.

**View Controller**

```swift
class BrowseViewController: UIViewController {

  var categoryItem: CategoryItem! = CategoryItem() //Category Item

  private func setupExplore() {
    //assign delegate of category item to controller
    self.categoryItem.delegate = self
  }
}

// delegate function to be called
extension BrowseViewController: ExploreDelegate {
  func categoryClicked(category: ProductCategory) {
    print("clicked")
    let categoryView = ProductByCategoryView()
    categoryView.category = category
    categoryView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryView, animated: true)
  }
}
```

**Explore.swift (subview)**

```swift
import UIKit

protocol ExploreDelegate: UIViewController {
  func categoryClicked(category: ProductCategory)
}

class Explore: UIView {
  var delegate: ExploreDelegate?

  class CategoryItem: UIView {
    var delegate: ExploreDelegate?
    var category: ProductCategory? {
      didSet {
        self.configure()
      }
    }

    var tapped: ((_ category: ProductCategory?) -> Void)?

    func configure() {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
      self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.categoryTapped)))
      self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    @objc func categoryTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
      delegate?.categoryClicked(category: ProductCategory.everything)
      self.tapped?(self.category)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a **print statement** inside categoryTapped.

You will then know if it is actually being tapped.

A million things could go wrong, for example, you may have forget to set the UIView to allow intertaction.

After checking that. **Next add another print statement inside categoryTapped which** shows you whether or not the `delegate` variable is null.

You'll quickly discover the problem using simple print statements.

```
print("I got to here!")
```

It's that easy.

And what about

```
if delegate == nil { print("it is nil!! oh no!" }
else { print("phew. it is NOT nil.") }
```

Debugging is really that easy at this level.

Next add a print statement ***inside*** `setupExplore()`

```
func setupExplore() {
  print("setup explore was called")
  ....
```

See what happens.

Comment: my button tap event works well as i have tested with print statements. The problem is that the delegate method don't get called.

Comment: hi @customapps - add a print statement which **prints the delegate variable**  - you'll see if it is there or not.  it's very likely nil.

Comment: do you mean like: **print(self.delegate!)**

Comment: hi @customapps - sure, simply print("try this! " + delegate) will work, no need for the self.

Comment: what about something like " if delegate == nil { print("it is nil!! oh no!" } else { print("phew. it is NOT nil.") }

Comment: delegate returns nil. what could be wrong with my delegate?

Comment: hi @customapps , as a new user U need to add upvotes to helpful answers. Also edit your code now pleaae to show ALL the print statements you have added.  Finally please note the new addition to my answer and try that.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any piece of code which sets the `delegate`.

First of all, define `delegate` as a property inside `CategoryItem` class, Then you must set the current instance of `BrowseViewController` to the `delegate` variable of `CategoryItem`. Now you can expect your method being called.

Comment: please review my code. i have effected the changes but same result

Comment: First, define `delegate` property as week to avoid memory leakage problem `weak var delegate: ExploreDelegate `. Then try to print out delegate inside funtion `@objc func categoryTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)` to determine delegate has value or not.

Comment: i did so. it returns null

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could cause the delegate method to not be triggered in this code:

1. Ensure that `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on your `CategoryItem`. This is probably best done in either the `configure()` function in the `CategoryItem` or in the `setupExplore()` function of the `BrowseViewController`.
2. Make sure that the `setupExplore()` function on the `BrowseViewController` is being called, and that the `category` is being set on the `CategoryItem` to trigger the `configure` function. Otherwise, either the delegate or the gesture recognizer might not being set.

### Side Note - `weak` vs `strong` delegate

On a side note, it is usually best practice to make your delegate properties `weak var` rather that having them be a strong reference, as this makes them prone to strong retain cycles.

Therefore, you might want to consider making the `var delegate: ExploreDelegate?` on your `CategoryItem` into `weak var delegate: ExploreDelegate?`. For more information on this problem, [view this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056526/swift-delegation-when-to-use-weak-pointer-on-delegate?rq=1).

Comment: delegate still returns nil

Comment: In that case, I'm going to need more information. In your question, can you please include the code where `setupExplore()` is called?